# rxjs 5 -> 6 migration: connect operator missing

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

We started upgrading `rxjs` from v5 to v6 (without using the compatibility layer, in case it makes any difference).

The majority of the changes are straight forward and well documented in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md. However, we are not sure at all and couldn't find any good documentation about the v5 `connect` operator.

We have the following snipper of code:

```
const syncStatesObservable = Observable.from(intervals)
    .concatMap(i =>
        fetchSyncState(i).concatMap(syncState => {
            if (syncState.version !== version) {
                logger.info(`Regenerate all entries: version ${version}`);
                return clearAndFetchSyncState(i);
            }
            return Observable.of(syncState);
        })
    )
    .publishReplay();

syncStatesObservable.connect();

// syncStatesObservable is then used in other streams
```

The equivalent v6 snippet (apart from the `connect` operator) looks like the following:

```
const syncStatesObservable = from(intervals).pipe(
    concatMap(i =>
        fetchSyncState(i).pipe(
            concatMap(syncState => {
                if (syncState.version !== version) {
                    logger.info(`Regenerate all entries: version ${version}`);
                    return clearAndFetchSyncState(i);
                }
                return of(syncState);
            })
        )
    ),
    publishReplay()
);

syncStatesObservable.connect(); // What to do here???
```

As per TypeScript, `Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

What would be the equivalent for the `connect` operator in `rxjs@6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is purely a TypeScript issue. We were able to fix it by typecasting the observable as follows:

```
const syncStatesObservable = from(intervals).pipe(
    concatMap(i =>
        fetchSyncState(i).pipe(
            concatMap(syncState => {
                if (syncState.version !== version) {
                    logger.info(`Regenerate all entries: version ${version}`);
                    return clearAndFetchSyncState(i);
                }
                return of(syncState);
            })
        )
    ),
    publishReplay()
) as ConnectableObservable<SyncState>;

syncStatesObservable.connect();
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2972